# how to emulate mysql not listening in a port using iptables?

Tags: php, mysql, iptables

I am using mysql_nd in php to connect to mysql databases and do failover between multiple slaves and master, so when mysql is not running on a server, everything works ok and all queries go to other servers.

I need to have mysql server up and running in the server but blocking all the incoming connections so mysql_nd driver in php thinks the server is down. I thought a simple REJECT with potables would be enough but is not; packets are being rejected, no mysql connection is established, but php app behaves differently, php threads waits and increase until get to the max.

If the mysql service is down, mysql_nd just detects it immediately, requests are forwarded to other servers, no slowdown, no php threads piling up on the web server.

Even with the mysql service running, as soon as I add or insert an iptbles rule with reject, requests are also forwarded to other servers but php piles up as if the connection to the mysql were kept open for any reason, so I am assuming rejecting packet with iptables to a port returns something different than the linux kernel having nothing listening in that port.

Is there a way to do this behavior with iptables?

Comment: Why not just execute a query in PHP code: `Select 1;` to check if server is up or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question; after some digging,  in linux I need to do a reject with specific tcp flag, otherwise the php threads will remain open and waiting until php timeout.

The proper iptables line will be:

iptables -A INPUT -s  xx.xx.xx.xx -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

This way, I can properly shutdown mysql service on slaves while php clients using mysql_nd  will detect immediately the service is down and redirect queries to the remaining slave servers.

Answer (score 0):

A server which is openly exposing a closed port will refuse the connection.  To me that seems well modeled by an iptables REJECT rule.  It's also probably what you'd get if your app server attempted to connect to the database while it was starting up, but before it was ready, so it's a valid case to handle, albeit one you might have to go out of your way to reproduce.  You should probably make this response work too.

A server that isn't responding at all, however, can't send a connection refused or reject any sorts of packets.  This behavior is better modeled by an iptables DROP, which simply discards the packet without and addional response.  The connection eventually times out on the client end, introducing some throttling to the client requests.

You can read more about difference between reject and drop here https://serverfault.com/questions/157375/reject-vs-drop-when-using-iptables but for your purposes suffice it to say that a server which cannot respond ( non existent or non functional) is modeled by DROP and on which will not respond (not listening on the port or explicitly rejecting ) is modeled by a REJECT.